# Charging through Stripe for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble charging a user through Stripe. The paymentResult object I receive in the following delegate method

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {

}
```

is a STPCard object, but according the documentation to complete a charge with my backend I need an STPToken. I've tried using

```
STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: card) {}
```

to create a STPToken with the STPCard object I received, but I get an error saying the card parameter doesn't have the required variable 'number'. Does anyone know what may be going on or if there is a way to complete a charge with just the STPCard object? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where STPPaymentContext calls didCreatePaymentResult on its delegate, the token has already been created, so there's no need to try to create a second token. I'd have a look at the example iOS backend, which works with the "standard" example application in the Stripe SDK:

https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where is this token? I can't find it in either STPPaymentContext or STPPaymentResult. Would it be stored in the backend, and then the backend charges?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `stripe id` from card instead of `token`, you need to include customer object, see [How to use Stripe and Apple Pay in iOS](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/219)

Here's how to handle that in Go

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "os"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/charge"
)

func main() {
    stripe.Key = "sk_test_mM2MkqO61n7vvbVRfeYmBgWm00Si2PtWab"

    http.HandleFunc("/request_charge", handleCharge)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

var customerId = "cus_Eys6aeP5xR89ab"

type PaymentResult struct {
    StripeId string `json:"stripe_id"`
}

func handleCharge(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var t PaymentResult
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    params := &stripe.ChargeParams{
        Amount:      stripe.Int64(150),
        Currency:    stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
        Description: stripe.String("Charge from my Go backend"),
        Customer: stripe.String(customerId),
    }

    params.SetSource(t.StripeId)
    ch, err := charge.New(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Could not process payment: %v", err)
        fmt.Println(ch)
        w.WriteHeader(400)
    }

    w.WriteHeader(200)
}
```